# Angular change detection: how to refresh only certain items?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

Let's say I have 100 divs on my screen generated by `*ngFor` that takes values from my object that has data like

`{A1: someObject, A2: someOtherObject..., J10: someOtherOtherObject}`

I click on A1 and then on J10 and they switch their values. It changed to this:

`{A1: someOtherOtherObject, A2: someOtherObject..., J10: someObject}`

How do I force Angular to only refresh two divs only holding A1 and J10 values? I am using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, in constructor I have `cd.detach()` and only call `cd.detectChanges()` whenever second click occurs. Judging from what I see and am able to understand, each div triggers their `*ngIf` so every single one of them is recreated.

**Is there anything I can do to either a) override what is being refreshed or b) choose what to detect changes against?**

[image]

Comment: Are you using `trackBy`?

Comment: @Wandrille oh, no... This sounds like something that I should investigate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [track the items](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby) in your list, `*ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackById"`.
Then it will not render all the items again.

```
trackById = trackBy('id');

...

export function trackBy(field: string): (_index: number, item: any) => string | number {
  return (_index: number, item: any) => {
    if (!item) {
      return null;
    }
    return item[field] as (string | number);
  };
}
```

Comment: This just increated the speed *dramatically*. I was aware of this function but had no experience with it before so it didn't come to mind. So nice to use my app now! Thanks a lot for an almost instant answer!

Comment: Take a look at this page: [angular-performance-checklist](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist). You can learn a lot about angular performance improvement